tcolorbox&listings with evolution from textlive 2017 to texlive 2023?
tcolorbox is an incredibly powerful package for formatting latex, Python, C code listings.
I'm coming back once again to an evolution from textlive 2017 to texlive 2023. My previous mwe had overlooked some small problems.
I wonder about 3 points now that I operate with texlive 2023
1 [package listings]why with the \lstdefinestyle command, the basicstyle parameter only accepts \ttfamily or itshape. This seems to contradict the doc accessible with texdoc listings.
2 [package tcolorbox]another problem the definition \newtcblisting{latex*}[1][ ] forces me to use this environment in the following way
\begin{latex*}[]
\section{Installation on Linux system}
\end{latex*}

otherwise the beginning of the content is eaten. How to modify the definition to simplify its use as follows
\begin{latex*}
    \section{Installation on Linux system}
\end{latex*}

3 [package tcolorbox] last problem why characters dropped after '\end{latex}' exactly on the same line. Clearly this is not very serious in itself because I never put anything there for reasons of presentation of source code.
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,shapes,patterns}

\tikzset{coltria/.style={fill=red!15!white}}
%-----------------
\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand{\orange}[1]{\textcolor{orange}{#1}}
\newcommand{\green}[1]{\textcolor{green}{#1}}

\lstdefinestyle{latexstyle}{      
    basicstyle=\ttfamily, % or itshape only
    columns=flexible,
    language=TeX,
    frame = none,
    commentstyle=\color{green},    % comment style
    breaklines}


%-------------------------
%   box dédiée au code latex avec titre
%-------------------------
\newtcblisting{latex}[2][]
{empty,breakable,leftrule=5mm,left=2mm,
    frame style={fill,top color=green!75!black,bottom color=green!75!black,middle color=green},
    listing only,
    listing engine=listings,
    listing options={style=latexstyle,tabsize=4,breaklines,
        breakindent=1.5em,columns=fullflexible},
    colback=yellow!15!white,
    %-------------------------
    % code for unbroken boxes:
    %-------------------------
    frame code={\path[tcb fill frame] (frame.south west)--(frame.north west)
        --([xshift=-5mm]frame.north east)--([yshift=-5mm]frame.north east)
        --([yshift=5mm]frame.south east)--([xshift=-5mm]frame.south east)--cycle; },
    interior code={\path[tcb fill interior] (interior.south west)--(interior.north west)
        --([xshift=-4.8mm]interior.north east)--([yshift=-4.8mm]interior.north east)
        --([yshift=4.8mm]interior.south east)--([xshift=-4.8mm]interior.south east)
        --cycle; },
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm},
    title=\fcolorbox{black}{black}{\red{#2}},
    %-------------------------
    % code for the first part of a break sequence:
    %-------------------------
    skin first is subskin of={emptyfirst}{%
        frame code={\path[tcb fill frame] (frame.south west)--(frame.north west)
            --([xshift=-5mm]frame.north east)--([yshift=-5mm]frame.north east)
            --(frame.south east)--cycle;
            \path[coltria] ([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=1mm]frame.south west) -- +(120:2mm)
            -- +(60:2mm)-- cycle; },
        interior code={\path[tcb fill interior] (interior.south west|-frame.south)
            --(interior.north west)--([xshift=-4.8mm]interior.north east)
            --([yshift=-4.8mm]interior.north east)--(interior.south east|-frame.south)
            --cycle; },
    },
    %-------------------------
    % code for the middle part of a break sequence:
    %-------------------------
    skin middle is subskin of={emptymiddle}{%
        frame code={\path[tcb fill frame] (frame.south west)--(frame.north west)
            --(frame.north east)--(frame.south east)--cycle;
            \path[coltria] ([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north west) -- +(240:2mm)
            -- +(300:2mm) -- cycle;
            \path[coltria] ([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=1mm]frame.south west) -- +(120:2mm)
            -- +(60:2mm) -- cycle;
        },
        interior code={\path[tcb fill interior] (interior.south west|-frame.south)
            --(interior.north west|-frame.north)--(interior.north east|-frame.north)
            --(interior.south east|-frame.south)--cycle; },
    },
    %-------------------------
    % code for the last part of a break sequence:
    %-------------------------
    skin last is subskin of={emptylast}{%
        frame code={\path[tcb fill frame] (frame.south west)--(frame.north west)
            --(frame.north east)--([yshift=5mm]frame.south east)
            --([xshift=-5mm]frame.south east)--cycle;
            \path[coltria] ([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north west) -- +(240:2mm)
            -- +(300:2mm) -- cycle;
        },
        interior code={\path[tcb fill interior] (interior.south west)
            --(interior.north west|-frame.north)--(interior.north east|-frame.north)
            --([yshift=4.8mm]interior.south east)--([xshift=-4.8mm]interior.south east)
            --cycle; }, #1}}

%-------------------------      
%   box dédiée au code latex sans titre
%-------------------------
\newtcblisting{latex*}[1][]
{empty,breakable,leftrule=5mm,left=2mm,
    frame style={fill,top color=green!75!black,bottom color=green!75!black,middle color=green},
    listing only,
    listing engine=listings,
    listing options={style=latexstyle,tabsize=4,breaklines,
        breakindent=1.5em,columns=fullflexible},
    colback=yellow!15!white,
    %   watermark color=red!50!yellow!75!white,
    %   watermark text on=unbroken is unbroken box,
    %   watermark text on=first is first part,
    %   watermark text on=middle is middle part,
    %   watermark text on=last is last part,
    %-------------------------
    % code for unbroken boxes:
    %-------------------------      
    frame code={\path[tcb fill frame] (frame.south west)--(frame.north west)
        --([xshift=-5mm]frame.north east)--([yshift=-5mm]frame.north east)
        --([yshift=5mm]frame.south east)--([xshift=-5mm]frame.south east)--cycle; },
    interior code={\path[tcb fill interior] (interior.south west)--(interior.north west)
        --([xshift=-4.8mm]interior.north east)--([yshift=-4.8mm]interior.north east)
        --([yshift=4.8mm]interior.south east)--([xshift=-4.8mm]interior.south east)
        --cycle; },
    %   attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-2mm},
    %   title=\fcolorbox{black}{black}{\red{#2}},
    %-------------------------
    % code for the first part of a break sequence:
    %-------------------------
    skin first is subskin of={emptyfirst}{%
        frame code={\path[tcb fill frame] (frame.south west)--(frame.north west)
            --([xshift=-5mm]frame.north east)--([yshift=-5mm]frame.north east)
            --(frame.south east)--cycle;
            \path[coltria] ([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=1mm]frame.south west) -- +(120:2mm)
            -- +(60:2mm)-- cycle; },
        interior code={\path[tcb fill interior] (interior.south west|-frame.south)
            --(interior.north west)--([xshift=-4.8mm]interior.north east)
            --([yshift=-4.8mm]interior.north east)--(interior.south east|-frame.south)
            --cycle; },
    },
    %-------------------------
    % code for the middle part of a break sequence:
    %-------------------------
    skin middle is subskin of={emptymiddle}{%
        frame code={\path[tcb fill frame] (frame.south west)--(frame.north west)
            --(frame.north east)--(frame.south east)--cycle;
            \path[coltria] ([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north west) -- +(240:2mm)
            -- +(300:2mm) -- cycle;
            \path[coltria] ([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=1mm]frame.south west) -- +(120:2mm)
            -- +(60:2mm) -- cycle;
        },
        interior code={\path[tcb fill interior] (interior.south west|-frame.south)
            --(interior.north west|-frame.north)--(interior.north east|-frame.north)
            --(interior.south east|-frame.south)--cycle; },
    },
    %-------------------------
    % code for the last part of a break sequence:
    %-------------------------
    skin last is subskin of={emptylast}{%
        frame code={\path[tcb fill frame] (frame.south west)--(frame.north west)
            --(frame.north east)--([yshift=5mm]frame.south east)
            --([xshift=-5mm]frame.south east)--cycle;
            \path[coltria] ([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north west) -- +(240:2mm)
            -- +(300:2mm) -- cycle;
        },
        interior code={\path[tcb fill interior] (interior.south west)
            --(interior.north west|-frame.north)--(interior.north east|-frame.north)
            --([yshift=4.8mm]interior.south east)--([xshift=-4.8mm]interior.south east)
            --cycle; }, #1}}            

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{latex*}[]
        \section{Installation sur système Linux}
        
        \begin{itemize}
            \setlength\itemsep{0.05em} %semble ok texte en vert si gtkpreambule-3-tcolobox présent pourquoi
            \item Pour l'installation minimale, installez le paquet \textbf{texlive};
            \index{texlive@\orange{texlive}}
            
            \item Pour le support de la langue française, installez le paquet \textbf{texlive-lang-french};
            \index{texlive@\orange{texlive-lang-french}}
            
            \item Pour une compilation de greffons bien utiles, installez le paquet \textbf{texlive-latex-extra};
            \index{texlive@\orange{texlive-latex-extra}}
            \item \green{Pour l'installation complète sans se poser de question au sujet des paquets supplémentaires, installez le paquet \textbf{texlive-full}
                \index{texlive@\orange{texlive-full}}
                \footnote{Lua\LaTeX, une variante de \LaTeX{} utilisant le langage de script Lua est également installée. je vous le recommande}}.
        \end{itemize}
        
        \subsection{Installation optimale pour Ubuntu}
        \section{Installation sur système Linux}
        
        \begin{itemize}
            \setlength\itemsep{0.05em} %semble ok texte en vert si gtkpreambule-3-tcolobox présent pourquoi
            \item Pour l'installation minimale, installez le paquet \textbf{texlive};
            \index{texlive@\orange{texlive}}
            
            \item Pour le support de la langue française, installez le paquet \textbf{texlive-lang-french};
            \index{texlive@\orange{texlive-lang-french}}
            
            \item Pour une compilation de greffons bien utiles, installez le paquet \textbf{texlive-latex-extra};
            \index{texlive@\orange{texlive-latex-extra}}
            \item \green{Pour l'installation complète sans se poser de question au sujet des paquets supplémentaires, installez le paquet \textbf{texlive-full}
                \index{texlive@\orange{texlive-full}}
                \footnote{Lua\LaTeX, une variante de \LaTeX{} utilisant le langage de script Lua est également installée. je vous le recommande}}.
        \end{itemize}
        
        \subsection{Installation optimale pour Ubuntu}
        \section{Installation sur système Linux}
        
        \begin{itemize}
            \setlength\itemsep{0.05em} %semble ok texte en vert si gtkpreambule-3-tcolobox présent pourquoi
            \item Pour l'installation minimale, installez le paquet \textbf{texlive};
            \index{texlive@\orange{texlive}}
            
            \item Pour le support de la langue française, installez le paquet \textbf{texlive-lang-french};
            \index{texlive@\orange{texlive-lang-french}}
            
            \item Pour une compilation de greffons bien utiles, installez le paquet \textbf{texlive-latex-extra};
            \index{texlive@\orange{texlive-latex-extra}}
            \item \green{Pour l'installation complète sans se poser de question au sujet des paquets supplémentaires, installez le paquet \textbf{texlive-full}
                \index{texlive@\orange{texlive-full}}
                \footnote{Lua\LaTeX, une variante de \LaTeX{} utilisant le langage de script Lua est également installée. je vous le recommande}}.
        \end{itemize}
        
        \subsection{Installation optimale pour Ubuntu}
        
    \end{latex*}

    \begin{latex}{exemple latex}
        \section{Installation sur système Linux}
        
        \begin{itemize}
            \setlength\itemsep{0.05em} %semble ok texte en vert si gtkpreambule-3-tcolobox présent pourquoi
            \item Pour l'installation minimale, installez le paquet \textbf{texlive};
            \index{texlive@\orange{texlive}}
            
            \item Pour le support de la langue française, installez le paquet \textbf{texlive-lang-french};
            \index{texlive@\orange{texlive-lang-french}}
            
            \item Pour une compilation de greffons bien utiles, installez le paquet \textbf{texlive-latex-extra};
            \index{texlive@\orange{texlive-latex-extra}}
            \item \green{Pour l'installation complète sans se poser de question au sujet des paquets supplémentaires, installez le paquet \textbf{texlive-full}
                \index{texlive@\orange{texlive-full}}
                \footnote{Lua\LaTeX, une variante de \LaTeX{} utilisant le langage de script Lua est également installée. je vous le recommande}}.
        \end{itemize}
        
        \subsection{Installation optimale pour Ubuntu}
    \end{latex} why Characters dropped after %\end{latex}

\end{document}


do not use the minimal class for examples, that is normally too minimal, use article. And why don't you use texlive 2024 if you are updating anyway?

Ok I got trapped again to make a MWE. So I went to the article class and bingo: basicstyle=\small, is running.
Regarding texlive I went to ubuntu 24.04LTS which gives access only to texlive2023. But I have some anomalies with tlmgr.
Nevertheless why not go to texlive2024. Is there a simple method to apply?

the reason \small or whatever didn't work is that minimal doesn't do a full font setup, so some font switching commands are expected to fail.

it is fairly normal to drop anything from the end of a verbatim environment to the end of the line. I can't remember off-hand, but this is probably just what listings does.

In order to explain to ulrike. I found the Best way to texlive 2024 is to burn DVD..other way dont run OK tl-install install 2023 version Only. Perhap I didn't understand some item. Thank you for help
